# Adding libraries to django nonrel

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I've a project in Django which I'm trying to port to Django-nonrel so that I can upload it to Google app Engine. I've installed django-nonrel and other required libraries by going through the http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

namely: django-nonrel
djangoappengine
djangotoolbox
django-autoload
django-dbindexer

that is by downloading their zip files and placing them in my app directory. 
So, my app directory is: 
>

```
<app>/autoload
<app>/dbindexer
<app>/django
<app>/djangoappengine
<app>/djangotoolbox
```

I also have django in my project directory and have started the project by:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python django/bin/django-admin.py startproject \
   --name=app.yaml --template=djangoappengine/conf/project_template app
```

If I am adding an external library with pip and adding it to the **INSTALLED_APPS** of my app's **settings.py** , it is not recognised by my django-nonrel which is pretty obvious considering the fact that django-nonrel is not installed on my system. It gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1390, in _warmup
    request_type=instance.READY_REQUEST)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 884, in _handle_request
    environ, wrapped_start_response)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 314, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1297, in _handle_script_request
    request_type)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1262, in _handle_instance_request
    request_type)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/instance.py", line 371, in handle
    raise CannotAcceptRequests('Instance has been quit')
CannotAcceptRequests: Instance has been quit
(nonrel)apurva@apurva-HP-ProBook-6470b:~/project/flogin$ python manage.py runserver
INFO     2015-08-11 16:06:54,606 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2015-08-11 16:06:55,511 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2015-08-11 16:06:55,633 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:60055
INFO     2015-08-11 16:06:55,847 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://127.0.0.1:8080
INFO     2015-08-11 16:06:55,847 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2015-08-11 16:06:58,966 __init__.py:52] Validating models...
ERROR    2015-08-11 16:06:59,045 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/home/apurva/project/flogin/djangoappengine/main/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    validate_models()
  File "/home/apurva/project/flogin/djangoappengine/main/__init__.py", line 55, in validate_models
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, None)
  File "/home/apurva/project/flogin/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/apurva/project/flogin/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/apurva/project/flogin/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/apurva/project/flogin/django/db/models/loading.py", line 97, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/home/apurva/project/flogin/django/utils/importlib.py", line 42, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named oauth2_provider
```

However, I'm unsure on how to add external libraries to my project. So that my django-nonrel recognises it. I've also tried google's documentation on how to this i.e.

> Adding Third-party Packages to the Application
>
> You can add any third-party library to your application, as long as it
>   is implemented in "pure Python" (no C extensions) and otherwise
>   functions in the App Engine runtime environment. The easiest way to
>   manage this is with a ./lib directory.
>
> Create a directory named lib in your application root directory:
>
> mkdir lib To tell your app how to find libraries in this directory,
>   create (or modify) a file named appengine_config.py in the root of
>   your project, then add these lines:
>
> from google.appengine.ext import vendor
>
> £ Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder. vendor.add('lib') Use pip with the -t lib flag to install libraries in this directory:
>
> `$ pip install -t lib gcloud` Note: pip version 6.0.0 or higher is
>   required for vendor to work properly.
>
> Tip: the appengine_config.py above assumes that the current working
>   directory is where the lib folder is located. In some cases, such as
>   unit tests, the current working directory can be different. To avoid
>   errors, you can explicity pass in the full path to the lib folder
>   using
>   vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**)),
>   'lib'))

didn't work either.

Comment: I don't understand the reference to also having Django in your project directory. django-nonrel *replaces* Django, and what is the difference between your app directory and your project directory?

Comment: Well Django is the django-nonrel folder. The app directory is after running the command I've mentioned that creates the app and the project directory is the directory that contains the app. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0):

So I had a very similar dilemma. Here is how I solved it:

Followed Google's instructions noted above, using `pip` and a `./lib` directory. Make sure you have an updated version of `pip`:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, because of `pkg_resources` issues, I did this:

```
pip install -t lib setuptools
```

That was necessary, I am just not sure if that was the right place to install setuptools or not. It certainly worked, though.

Then, I launched the local development server like this, in the project directory:

```
PYTHONPATH=lib ./manage.py runserver
```

I hope that works for you!